# not working vmware 12.5.1 on linux mint 18.3

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, vmware

**i'll install vmware 12.0 but it is not working**.
*i'll try to install kernel but it is not work*
[image]

log file details

```
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=30222 version=12.5.1 build=build-4542065 option=Release
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Host is Linux 4.10.0-40-generic 
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/virajlinux/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/virajlinux/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/virajlinux/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.370+05:30| vthread-4| I125: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.454+05:30| vthread-4| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-30222.log
2018-01-05T21:42:52.465+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.465+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.465+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.10.0-40-generic to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.465+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.465+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:52.471+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.471+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:52.681+05:30| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-05T21:42:52.681+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Read 21375 symbol versions
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.704+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.706+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.706+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.707+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.707+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.709+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.709+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.710+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.710+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.711+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.726+05:30| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2018-01-05T21:42:52.726+05:30| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2018-01-05T21:42:52.744+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-05T21:42:52.744+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.10.0-40-generic to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.744+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.744+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:52.750+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:52.750+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:52.987+05:30| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-05T21:42:52.987+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.021+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Read 21375 symbol versions
2018-01-05T21:42:53.021+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include
2018-01-05T21:42:53.021+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include
2018-01-05T21:42:53.021+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.021+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:53.028+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.028+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:53.029+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2018-01-05T21:42:53.032+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.032+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.032+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.035+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.035+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.037+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.037+05:30| vthread-4| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.037+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.037+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.037+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:53.046+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.046+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:53.047+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.047+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.047+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:53.071+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.071+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:53.071+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.077+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.077+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.10.0-40-generic to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.077+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.077+05:30| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2018-01-05T21:42:53.083+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-40-generic".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.084+05:30| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-01-05T21:42:53.312+05:30| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-01-05T21:42:53.312+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.347+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Read 21375 symbol versions
2018-01-05T21:42:53.347+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.349+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.349+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.351+05:30| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.870+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.870+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2018-01-05T21:42:53.879+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2018-01-05T21:42:53.879+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-f2V5NG/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-01-05T21:42:56.129+05:30| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2018-01-05T21:42:56.131+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2018-01-05T21:42:56.131+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2018-01-05T21:42:56.136+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2018-01-05T21:42:56.136+05:30| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-f2V5NG/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.10.0-40-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-01-05T21:42:58.370+05:30| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Comment: from a superficial reading it seems either you don't have sufficient privileges or you haven't given sufficient privileges. Is this a local or a remote installation ?

Comment: See: [“Failed to build vmnet” for kernel 3.19](https://askubuntu.com/q/617704/78223) and [Failed to build vmnet](https://askubuntu.com/q/666445/78223).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [post](https://askubuntu.com/q/617704/78223), most likely you need to patch your vmware installation in order to compile the modules. The instructions how to build VMware Tools are provided at [`vmware-tools-patches` project page](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches).